# Why did Weevil go back to his previous life?

Tags: character, veronica-mars-2014

In [Veronica Mars the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_Mars_%28film%29#Plot), why did Weevil go back to his previous life of crime?

I am referring to one of the last scenes of the movie: Veronica looks out from a window and sees Weevil dressed like a biker with his old gang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan Sepinwall feels this is [part of a theme](http://www.hitfix.com/whats-alan-watching/the-veronica-mars-movie-spoiler-review) in the movie:

> Veronica isn't the only one who gets sucked back into old patterns.
>   Getting shot and having to clear his name puts Weevil back on a bike
>   for the first time since his daughter was born, and with the rest of
>   the PCHers for the first time since high school. And though Wallace is
>   being a responsible grown-up (for now), Mac is once again doing
>   Veronica's hacker bidding.

In the comments there is more discussion about Weevil's change:

> Veronica told him that some "stoolie" was claiming he personally sold
>   the gun to Weevil, presumably because the sheriff's department was
>   forcing him to. Veronica said "He clearly fears the police more than
>   he fears you." Than Weevil said "Yeah, well. We'll see what we can do
>   about that." So like Alan said, he's back to being a gangster in order
>   to clear his name.

Of course, the real reason is that this allows for potential story-lines in a sequel movie/book/comic.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation i know for that comes from the scene where Veronica talks about the guy testifying that he sold Weevil the gun, and how he's afraid from the sheriff more than Weevil, and he responded with something like "that's gonna change" implying that he's going back to his old gang so he can prove his innocence and fight back. (Also I think it's interesting that he find himself returning to his old life the same way as Veronica)

Comment: That's not true. In one of the last scene of the movie, we see him with is old gang on the bike.

Comment: @mattiav27 Ah I forgot about that scene. Now your Question (after editing) makes since. I'll edit my answer